# Find probability in card question

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that a test for extrasensory perception consists
of naming (in any order) $3$ cards randomly drawn from
a deck of $13$ cards. Find the probability that by chance
alone, the person will correctly name (a) no cards, (b) $1$
card.

this is what I got

a) $f(0)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3  \\
0  \\
 \end{array} \right)   (10/13)^3= 45.5$%

b)$f(1)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3  \\
1  \\
 \end{array} \right) (3/13)  (10/13)^2=40.96$%

but the book says a) $42$% and b $47.2$%. I really need to understand this. So would anyone please show me where I am wrong.

Comment: 1) are they drawn w/replacement? 2) are all cards unique?

Comment: The three picks are not identical trials so the binomial formula doesn't apply (it would apply if you picked with replacement).

Comment: The person knows which cards are 13 cards in the deck? Or is randomly selected package of 32 cards a person does not know is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Assuming that each card is unique:

- The number of different ways to pick $3$ cards out of all $13$ cards is $\binom{13}{3}=286$
- The number of different ways to pick $3$ cards out of the $10$ cards **not** drawn is $\binom{10}{3}=120$
- So the probability that a person will name $0$ cards correctly is $\displaystyle\frac{120}{286}=41.9\%$

---

B) Assuming that each card is unique:

- The number of different ways to pick $3$ cards out of all $13$ cards is $\binom{13}{3}=286$
- The number of different ways to pick $2$ cards out of the $10$ cards **not** drawn is $\binom{10}{2}=45$
- The number of different ways to pick $1$ card out of the $3$ cards drawn is $\binom{3}{1}=3$
- So the probability that a person will name $1$ card correctly is $\displaystyle\frac{45\cdot3}{286}=47.2\%$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cards are drawn without replacement and are each uniques, Barak's answer is correct for part (a). Diane's answers are right if the cards are drawn *with* replacement.

The book obviously meant the cards are drawn without replacement.

For part (b) the answer is 
$$
\binom{3}{1} \frac{3}{13} \frac{10}{12} \frac{9}{11} = \frac{135}{286}
$$
which is 47.2%.

(Barak's method is superior but I gave a more step-by-step way to reach the same number because Barak already showed the couning-cases way.)